# Concatenate LSTM with CNN with different tensors' dimentions in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

this is two neuron networks that I tried to merge by using concatenate operation. The network should classify IMDB movies reviews by 1-good and 0-bad movies

```
def cnn_lstm_merged():
       embedding_vecor_length = 32
       cnn_model = Sequential()
       cnn_model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
       cnn_model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
       cnn_model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
       cnn_model.add(Flatten())

       lstm_model = Sequential()
       lstm_model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
       lstm_model.add(LSTM(64, activation = 'relu'))
       lstm_model.add(Flatten())

       merge = concatenate([lstm_model, cnn_model])
       hidden = (Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))(merge)
       #print(model.summary())
       output = hidden.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)
       return output
```

But when I run the code there is an error:

```
  File "/home/pythonist/Desktop/EnsemblingLSTM_CONV/train.py", line 59, in cnn_lstm_merged
    lstm_model.add(Flatten())
  File "/home/pythonist/deeplearningenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 185, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/home/pythonist/deeplearningenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 414, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/home/pythonist/deeplearningenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 327, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_2: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2
[Finished in 4.8s with exit code 1]
```

How to merge these two layers? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use the `Flatten` after the `LSTM` as the `LSTM` (per default) only returns the *last* state and not a sequence, i.e. the data will have the shape `(BS, n_output)` but the `Flatten` layer expects a shape of `(BS, a, b)` which will be transformed into `(BS, a*b)`.

So, either remove the `Flatten` layer and work just with the last state or add `return_sequences=True` to the `LSTM`. This will make the `LSTM` to return all outputs and not just the last one, i.e. `(BS, T, n_out)`.

**Edit**: Also, the way how you created the final model is wrong. Please take a look at [this](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.0/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) example; for you, it should be something like this:

```
  merge = Concatenate([lstm_model, cnn_model])
  hidden = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
  conc_model = Sequential()
  conc_model.add(merge)
  conc_model.add(hidden)
  conc_model.compile(...)

  output = conc_model .fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)
```

All in all, it might be better to use the [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

**Edit 2**: This is the final code

```
cnn_model = Sequential()
cnn_model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
cnn_model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
cnn_model.add(Flatten())

lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
lstm_model.add(LSTM(64, activation = 'relu', return_sequences=True))
lstm_model.add(Flatten())

# instead of the last two lines you can also use
# lstm_model.add(LSTM(64, activation = 'relu'))
# then you do not have to use the Flatten layer. depends on your actual needs

merge = Concatenate([lstm_model, cnn_model])
hidden = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
conc_model = Sequential()
conc_model.add(merge)
conc_model.add(hidden)
```

Comment: I did it but I've got another error:   File "/home/pythonist/deeplearningenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 285, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
ValueError: Layer concatenate_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>. Full input: [<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7f4468e36c50>, <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7f448a0a1320>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
[Finished in 4.7s with exit code 1]

Comment: That is because you are trying to concatenate sequential models. Convert the same to functional keras model and then concatenate. It will work for sure. @SuleymanSuleyman-zade

Comment: @UpasanaMittal You can also do this using the old, sequential models (see my edit), but still - using the functional API is much more intuitive and easier, that's correct.

Comment: I'm sorry but how to convert it? I tried do use many configurations but it still has an error with different and inconsistent dimensions.

Comment: @SuleymanSuleyman-zade I added a working version of the code.

Comment: conc_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics='accuracy'])
 output = conc_model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3, batch_size=64)
 return output

Comment: thank you but here I have another problem with fitting (trainig) of data: raise ValueError('A `Concatenate` layer should be called '
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs

Comment: x_train.shape is (25000, 5),  y_train.shape is (25000)

Comment: I had the same error as Suleyman. Has the problem been fixed ? If so let me know, thanks